# Using MySQL join and taking the row from different insert ids

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT pb.*
     , expire_date IS NULL permanent
     , p.username banned_by 
  FROM player_bans pb 
  JOIN players p 
    ON pb.by_userid = p.id 
 WHERE (ip = '%e' OR userid = '%d') 
   AND (expire_date > NOW() OR expire_date IS NULL) 
   AND liftedby_userid IS NULL 
 LIMIT 1
```

As you can see, the query joins the "players" table and gets the "username" row. I also want to get the userid's (this userid field exists at the player_bans table) name on the players table by joining the tables, how can I do this at the same query?

So basically, I want to do the same thing done with by_userid, but for the "userid" field this time in the same query.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. For further help, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pb.*
     , (expire_date IS NULL) AS permanent
     , p1.username AS banned_by
     , p2.username AS player
FROM player_bans pb
JOIN players p1 ON pb.by_userid = p1.id
JOIN players p2 ON pb.userid = p2.id
WHERE (ip = '127.0.0.1' OR userid = 1)
  AND (expire_date > NOW() OR expire_date IS NULL)
  AND (liftedby_userid IS NULL)
```

This is how I solved it.